# Twitter bootstrap grid adding up to > 100%?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I am using the twitter bootstrap grid.

I am trying to use:

```
<div id="footer-groups" class="row-fluid collapse in">
    <div class="span3">
        Users
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        Clients
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        Projects
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        Tasks
    </div>
</div>
```

But for some reason the width + margin-left is adding up to `101.309328969%`

I am using the less version of bootstrap 2.2.2 (as 2.3 does not compile through lessphp!).

The strange thing is, this only happens if I have one file (custom.less)

That contains:

```
@import "bootstrap.less"
@import "responsive.less"
```

If I include these two separately then it works fine.

I am using font awesome.

I do have a bootswatch theme in use, but it does not modify the grid as far as I am aware, it uses these two files

variables.less (diff)
diff variables.less variables.default.less

```
1c1
< // Cerulean 2.3.0
---
> //
6c6
< // GLOBAL VALUES
---
> // Global values
17c17
< @grayLighter:           #F5F5F5;
---
> @grayLighter:           #eee;
23,30c23,30
< @blue:                  #2FA4E7;
< @blueDark:              #033C73;
< @green:                 #73A839;
< @red:                   #C71C22;
< @yellow:                #F7B42C;
< @orange:                #DD5600;
< @pink:                  #F49AC1;
< @purple:                #9760B3;
---
> @blue:                  #049cdb;
> @blueDark:              #0064cd;
> @green:                 #46a546;
> @red:                   #9d261d;
> @yellow:                #ffc40d;
> @orange:                #f89406;
> @pink:                  #c3325f;
> @purple:                #7a43b6;
36c36
< @textColor:             @gray;
---
> @textColor:             @grayDark;
41c41
< @linkColor:             @blue;
---
> @linkColor:             #08c;
49c49
< @monoFontFamily:        Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
---
> @monoFontFamily:        Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
54c54
< @altFontFamily:         @monoFontFamily;
---
> @altFontFamily:         @serifFontFamily;
56c56
< @headingsFontFamily:    'Telex', sans-serif; // empty to use BS default, @baseFontFamily
---
> @headingsFontFamily:    inherit; // empty to use BS default, @baseFontFamily
58c58
< @headingsColor:         #317EAC; // empty to use BS default, @textColor
---
> @headingsColor:         inherit; // empty to use BS default, @textColor
71c71
< @paddingMini:           0px 6px;   // 22px
---
> @paddingMini:           0 6px;   // 22px
82c82
< @tableBackgroundHover:              #e6e6e6; // for hover
---
> @tableBackgroundHover:              #f5f5f5; // for hover
89c89
< @btnBorder:                         darken(@white, 20%);
---
> @btnBorder:                         #bbb;
92c92
< @btnPrimaryBackgroundHighlight:     spin(@btnPrimaryBackground, 15%);
---
> @btnPrimaryBackgroundHighlight:     spin(@btnPrimaryBackground, 20%);
94c94
< @btnInfoBackground:                 @purple;
---
> @btnInfoBackground:                 #5bc0de;
97c97
< @btnSuccessBackground:              @green;
---
> @btnSuccessBackground:              #62c462;
100c100
< @btnWarningBackground:              @orange;
---
> @btnWarningBackground:              lighten(@orange, 15%);
103c103
< @btnDangerBackground:               @red;
---
> @btnDangerBackground:               #ee5f5b;
106c106
< @btnInverseBackground:              @blueDark;
---
> @btnInverseBackground:              #444;
146c146
< @zindexTooltip:           1020;
---
> @zindexTooltip:           1030;
183,193c183,193
< @navbarHeight:                    50px;
< @navbarBackgroundHighlight:       lighten(@navbarBackground, 8%);
< @navbarBackground:                @blue;
< @navbarBorder:                    darken(@navbarBackground, 8%);
< 
< @navbarText:                      @grayLighter;
< @navbarLinkColor:                 @white;
< @navbarLinkColorHover:            @white;
< @navbarLinkColorActive:           @navbarLinkColorHover;
< @navbarLinkBackgroundHover:       darken(@navbarBackground, 12%);
< @navbarLinkBackgroundActive:      darken(@navbarBackground, 12%);
---
> @navbarHeight:                    40px;
> @navbarBackgroundHighlight:       #ffffff;
> @navbarBackground:                darken(@navbarBackgroundHighlight, 5%);
> @navbarBorder:                    darken(@navbarBackground, 12%);
> 
> @navbarText:                      #777;
> @navbarLinkColor:                 #777;
> @navbarLinkColorHover:            @grayDark;
> @navbarLinkColorActive:           @gray;
> @navbarLinkBackgroundHover:       transparent;
> @navbarLinkBackgroundActive:      darken(@navbarBackground, 5%);
198,200c198,200
< @navbarInverseBackground:                @blueDark;
< @navbarInverseBackgroundHighlight:       lighten(@navbarInverseBackground, 5%);
< @navbarInverseBorder:                    darken(@navbarInverseBackground, 3%);
---
> @navbarInverseBackground:                #111111;
> @navbarInverseBackgroundHighlight:       #222222;
> @navbarInverseBorder:                    #252525;
202,203c202,203
< @navbarInverseText:                      @white;
< @navbarInverseLinkColor:                 @white;
---
> @navbarInverseText:                      @grayLight;
> @navbarInverseLinkColor:                 @grayLight;
205,207c205,207
< @navbarInverseLinkColorActive:           @white;
< @navbarInverseLinkBackgroundHover:       darken(@navbarInverseBackground, 6%);
< @navbarInverseLinkBackgroundActive:      darken(@navbarInverseBackground, 6%);
---
> @navbarInverseLinkColorActive:           @navbarInverseLinkColorHover;
> @navbarInverseLinkBackgroundHover:       transparent;
> @navbarInverseLinkBackgroundActive:      @navbarInverseBackground;
209c209
< @navbarInverseSearchBackground:          @white;
---
> @navbarInverseSearchBackground:          lighten(@navbarInverseBackground, 25%);
212c212
< @navbarInverseSearchPlaceholderColor:    @grayLight;
---
> @navbarInverseSearchPlaceholderColor:    #ccc;
233,234c233,234
< @warningText:             @orange;
< @warningBackground:       #F1CEAB;
---
> @warningText:             #c09853;
> @warningBackground:       #fcf8e3;
237,238c237,238
< @errorText:               darken(#C45559, 5%);
< @errorBackground:         #F2BDB1;
---
> @errorText:               #b94a48;
> @errorBackground:         #f2dede;
241,242c241,242
< @successText:             darken(@green, 5%);
< @successBackground:       #D5ECBF;
---
> @successText:             #468847;
> @successBackground:       #dff0d8;
245,246c245,246
< @infoText:                darken(@blue, 10%);
< @infoBackground:          #A7DFF1;
---
> @infoText:                #3a87ad;
> @infoBackground:          #d9edf7;
```

bootswatch.less

```
// Cerulean 2.3.0
// Bootswatch
// -----------------------------------------------------


// TYPOGRAPHY
// -----------------------------------------------------

@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Telex);

// SCAFFOLDING
// -----------------------------------------------------

// NAVBAR
// -----------------------------------------------------

.navbar {

    .brand {
        padding: 14px 20px 16px;
        font-family: @headingsFontFamily;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    li {
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    .nav > li > a {
        padding: 16px 10px 14px;
        font-family: @headingsFontFamily;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    .search-query {
        border: 1px solid darken(@linkColor, 10%);
        line-height: normal;
    }

    .navbar-text {
        padding: 19px 10px 18px;
        line-height: 13px;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    }

    &-inverse {

        .navbar-search .search-query {
            color: @textColor;
        }
    }
}

@media (max-width: @navbarCollapseWidth) {

    .navbar .nav-collapse {

        .nav li > a {

            font-family: @headingsFontFamily;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: @white;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

            &:hover {
                background-color: #2B7CAC;
            }
        }

        .nav .active > a {
            .box-shadow(none);
            background-color: #2B7CAC;
        }

        .dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
        .dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
        .dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
            background-image: none;
        }

        .navbar-form,
        .navbar-search {
            border: none;
        }

        .nav-header {
            color: #2B7CAC;
        }
    }

    .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse {

        .nav li > a {
            color: @navbarInverseLinkColor;

            &:hover {
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            }
        }

        .nav .active > a,
        .nav > li > a:hover,
        .dropdown-menu a:hover {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
        }
    }
}

div.subnav {

    font-family: @headingsFontFamily;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);

    &-fixed {
        top: @navbarHeight + 1;
    }
}

// NAV
// -----------------------------------------------------

// BUTTONS
// -----------------------------------------------------

.btn {
  #gradient > .vertical-three-colors(@white, @white, 5%, darken(@white, 0%));
  @shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  .box-shadow(@shadow);

  &:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}

.btn-primary {
  .buttonBackground(lighten(@btnPrimaryBackground, 5%), @btnPrimaryBackground);
}

.btn-info {
  .buttonBackground(lighten(@btnInfoBackground, 5%), @btnInfoBackground);
}

.btn-success {
  .buttonBackground(lighten(@btnSuccessBackground, 5%), @btnSuccessBackground);
}

.btn-warning {
  .buttonBackground(lighten(@btnWarningBackground, 5%), @btnWarningBackground);
}

.btn-danger {
  .buttonBackground(lighten(@btnDangerBackground, 5%), @btnDangerBackground);
}

.btn-inverse {
  .buttonBackground(lighten(@btnInverseBackground, 5%), @btnInverseBackground);
}

// TABLES
// -----------------------------------------------------

// FORMS
// -----------------------------------------------------

// DROPDOWNS
// -----------------------------------------------------

// ALERTS, LABELS, BADGES
// -----------------------------------------------------

// MISC
// -----------------------------------------------------

i[class^="icon-"]{
    opacity: 0.8;
}

// MEDIA QUERIES
// -----------------------------------------------------
```

The complete compiled css can be viewed here https://gist.github.com/hailwood/4751104

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with it, but have you tried wrapping your row inside a container (fluid)?

Comment: Whoops, it actually is, I just forgot to include that line!

Comment: Is there any styling on #footer-groups?

Comment: No styling there at all, it's actually not just that group, it's anywhere that the columns add to 12.